# Render the Role description correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles

I´m new to rails and I have users. Every of this users got a role through a role_id. Those roles have descriptions like `admin, customer` and so on. I want to show the role in the list of users detail page.

My code looks like this:

```
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 70 %>
<p3>
  <%= user.firstname %> <%= user.name %><br>
</p3>
<p4>
  <%=user.email %><br>
  Role:<br>xxxxxx
</p4>
```

What I have to write for the `xxxxxx` to show the `role description`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display role then following is way

Update 1:
If user table have one role

```
Role: <br> <%= user.role.try(:description) %>
```

Update 2:
If user table has many roles

```
Role: <br> <%= user.roles.pluck(:description).join(",") %>
```

Comment: i did: Rolle: <%=user.role_ids %> and he shows the Role ID (1,2,3,4....) but not description when i do :
Rolle: <%=user.role_ids  (:description)%> then he say wrong number of argument

Comment: @Feidex  You want to display `role ids` or `role description`?

Comment: i want to display role description.

Comment: Role: <br> <%= user.roles.pluck(:description).join(",") %> works 

Thank you :)

Comment: @Feidex Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I am considering the below relationship:

```
class User
  has_one :role
end

class Role
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And Role table contains the attributes like `id, description`. 
So, for displaying description(admin, customer,user, etc) , use the below:

```
Role: <br> <%= user.role.description %>
```

Comment: i did this through assignments:

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, through: :assignments

and 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments

Comment: ok, means you have multiple roles for a  user, so you can display the first role like user.roles.first.description